# why list view shows overwritten items; think problem in xml layout file

Tags: android, list, android-cursoradapter

I am building a list box manipulated by cursor adapter.  I have written the code below. RoomShare is the activity which holds the list. MessDatabase is the class that extends from SQLiteOpenHelper. TempDataFromDB is the temporary class that holds the record derived from DB.DB2CursorAdapter is the cursor adapter. 
In RoomShare activity I am creating the MessDatabase object(derived from SQLiteOpenHelper). In the constructor of MessDatabase, I am creating table "Share_room" and adding a row to it Then Select* query is run on cursor.Then DB2CursorAdapter object is created. In the newView of DB2CursorAdapter, I am populating 2 textviews. 
When I populate 2 textViews, the list item appears overwritten. But when I use 1 textview, in db_cursor_roomShare.xml, everything is fine. I think some problem with xml file.

```
public class RoomShare extends AppCompatActivity {

    DB2CursorAdapter DBAdapter;
    MessDatabase mdb;
    Cursor cursor;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_room_share);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TempDataFromDB.TABLE_NAME /*+ " ORDER BY " +
                TempDataFromDB.COLUMN_MESS_NAME + " DESC"*/;
        //this.deleteDatabase("ShareRoom_db");

        mdb = new MessDatabase(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = mdb.getWritableDatabase();//getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);

        DBAdapter = new DB2CursorAdapter(this, cursor);
        final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        listview.setAdapter(DBAdapter);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                /*Snackbar.make(view, "text u", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();*/
            }
        });

        db.close();

    }
```

---

```
public class MessDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ShareRoom_db";

    public MessDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(TempDataFromDB.CREATE_TABLE);
        //insertMessName("Demo");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TempDataFromDB.TABLE_NAME +
                "(" + TempDataFromDB.COLUMN_MESS_NAME +
                ")" + "VALUES " + "('One')");
    }
```

---

```
public class DB2CursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater cursorInflater;

    public DB2CursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context,cursor);
        System.out.println("Sandeep1");

        /*cursorInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);*/


    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        // R.layout.list_row is your xml layout for each row
        System.out.println("Sandeep2");
        cursorInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        return cursorInflater.inflate(R.layout.db_cursor_room_share, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        System.out.println("Sandeep3");

        TextView tvBody = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvBody);
        TextView tvPriority = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPriority);
        // Extract properties from cursor
        String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(TempDataFromDB.COLUMN_ID)));
        String mess_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TempDataFromDB.COLUMN_MESS_NAME));
        Toast toast=Toast.makeText(context,mess_name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
         toast.show();//----This is printing perfectly one
        // Populate fields with extracted properties
        tvBody.setText(id);
        tvPriority.setText(mess_name);
        System.out.println("Sandeep4");

    }
```

---

```
public class TempDataFromDB {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Share_room";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_PARTICIPANTS = "Participants";
    public static final String COLUMN_MESS_NAME = "Mess_Name";


    private int id;
    private String Participants;
    String[] arrayParticipants;
    private String Mess_Name;


    // Create table SQL query
    public static final String CREATE_TABLE =
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                    + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                    + COLUMN_PARTICIPANTS+ " TEXT,"
                    + COLUMN_MESS_NAME+"TEXT"
                    + ")";

    public TempDataFromDB() {
    }

    public TempDataFromDB(int id, String Participants,String Mess) {
        this.id = id;
        this.Participants = Participants;
        this.Mess_Name = Mess;
    }
```

---

db_cursor_roomShare.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match parent"

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/tvBody"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Study cursors"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/tvBody"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="mess name"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

activity_room_share.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RoomShare"

     <ListView android:id="@+id/listview"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:weight="1"/>
     <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

         <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
             android:id="@+id/toolbar"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
             android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
             app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/
     </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have data in sqlite database, before populating listview?

Comment: mdb = new MessDatabase(this);
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(TempDataFromDB.CREATE_TABLE);
        //insertMessName("Demo");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TempDataFromDB.TABLE_NAME +
                "(" + TempDataFromDB.COLUMN_MESS_NAME +
                ")" + "VALUES " + "(One)");
    } is run before listview is called

Comment: Do I have to create DB or public MessDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
will do the required thing?

Comment: Try to add this after setting adapter on list view `DBAdapter.changeCursor(cursor);`